# When reading values from a CSV, how to I push into a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I have a CSV file that contains 50 rows and 3 columns of numbers. As I read the rows from the file, I want to put them in an array and push that array into my two-dimensional array. How do I accomplish this?

Caveats:

- I have to use a two-dimensional array.
- I have to use `File`, `FileReader`, and `BufferedReader`.

My CSV file looks like this:

(day, high temp, low temp)

```
1,45,20
2,41,21
3,39,20
4,37,18
5,40,19
6,42,19
7,43,19
etc..
```

I want to have each line as its own array. Here is my code so far:

```java
public class Temps {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File fileName = new File("DaysAndTemps.csv");
    if (fileName.exists()) {
      BufferedReader br = null;
      String line = "";
      String cvsSplitBy = ",";
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("December 2020: Temperaturs");
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Day " + "High " + "Low " + "Variance");
      final int rows = 50;
      final int cols = 3;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[][] matrix = new String[rows][cols];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
          for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            matrix[row][col] = br.readLine();
          }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output currrently:

```
[[2,41,21, 3,39,20, 4,37,18], [5,40,19, 6,42,19, 7,43,19], [8,42,20, 9,39,19, 10,36,20], [11,35,20, 12,32,18, 13,31,16], [14,28,23, 15,35,20, 16,43,28] etc..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your while loop to this

```java
String[][] matrix = new String[rows][cols];
int row = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    String[] items = line.split(",");
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        matrix[row][col] = items[col];
    }
    row++;
}
```

Comment: I realized I had the creation of my two-dimensional array inside my while loop. I moved it out but it's still inserting a bunch of null values.

Comment: [[1, 40, 25], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], etc.. 
[[1, 40, 25], [2, 41, 21], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], etc..
[[1, 40, 25], [2, 41, 21], [3, 39, 20], [null, null, null], [null, null, null],
[[1, 40, 25], [2, 41, 21], [3, 39, 20], [4, 37, 18], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], etc..
[[1, 40, 25], [2, 41, 21], [3, 39, 20], [4, 37, 18], [5, 40, 19], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null]  etc..

Comment: do you have empty lines in you file? did you use my code or you just altered yours?

Comment: i have updated the code with an `if line.isEmpty` in case you have empty lines

Comment: I'm glad i helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try I can suggest an easier and more comprehensive solution.

just create a one-dimension array and then add an easily constructed one-demotion array to that array.

```java
File fileName = new File("C:\\descktop\\Portfolio" +
        "\\testFrorAnswers\\src\\com\\company\\res.csv");

if (fileName.exists()) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("December 2020: Temperaturs");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Day " + "High " + "Low " + "Variance");

    final int rows = 50;
    final int cols = 3;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Object[] a = new Object[50];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            String[] array = br.readLine().split(",");
            a[row] = array;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    }
}
```

the result is the following

```
[2, 41, 21], [3, 39, 20], [4, 37, 18], [5, 40, 19], [6, 42, 19], [7, 43, 19], etc...
```

try it

Comment: It needs to be a two-dimensional array, it is a requirement.